# Get original version of IE in Java script when a domain is added Microsoft Compatibility view list

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

One of our domain added into Microsoft Compatible view list with IE 10(https://iecvlist.microsoft.com/IE11/1387494476607/iecompatviewlist.xml) and we can't remove it. when I take browser version from navigator.userAgent then it gives the version as IE 10(as in Microsoft Compatible view list) instead of true version. How to get it ?

Even I add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`, the userAgent gives as IE10 instead latest version. How to get true IE version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out myself, The below snippet would identify whether the browser is true IE 10 or not though you access the page in IE 11 version and the domain is added in Microsoft compatible view list

```
if(Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()){
    console.log('TRUE IE10 Version');
}
```